# In C#. How do I print the subtotal and total(which includes tax) of a user's order using a loop

Tags: c#

- Question says output must be formatted with each option like this.

  1. Pizza
  2. Pop
  3. Goodbye
- Selection 1 adds pizza etc and 3 exits the loop.
- Pizza or pop will be added to the order for every option 1 or 2 entered.
- After loop finishes, subtotal should be printed in the same line as "subtotal".
- Subtotal is added correctly with pop included.
- Total must be correct with several pizza and pop
- Add 9% tax to subtotal
- Print line with * for each pizza purchased
- print line with * with every soda purchased

This is what i have so far.

```
        do
        {

            Console.WriteLine("1. pizza");
            Console.WriteLine("2. pop");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Goodbye");

            Console.Write("Select an option:");
            int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (choice == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Add a pizza to the order:$");
            }
                else if (choice == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Add a pop to the order:$");
            }

                 else if (choice == 3)
            {
                  Console.WriteLine("Exit");
                  break;
            }
                  else
            {
```

Comment: use a do/while loop and switch/case for the input. Those two are the basis of all programm flow in Console applications.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define

```
int pizza = 0;
int pop = 0;
```

I'm not sure what needs to be printed, but you will need to do `pizza++`; when `pizza` is chosen, `pop++` when `pop` is chosen. I'm not sure what the prices are, but, assuming that based on the value of `pizza` and `pop`, after the loop you compute `subtotal` somehow, adding 9% to it is the same as `subtotal *= 1.09;`.